# Cannot find a differ supporting object angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

Hi I am using Angular 7

I created service user-report.service.ts
for get method is not printing in browser

```
getReport() {
        /*this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/report`)
            .subscribe(res => console.log(res._body));*/
        return this
           .http
           .get(`${this.apiUrl}/report`);
    }
```

**user-report.component.ts**

```
getReport() {
        this.userReport.getReport()
            .subscribe((data: UserReport[]) => {
            this.reports = data;
            console.log(data);
    });
    }
```

**template**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
  <tr>
      <td>User Name</td>
      <td>Created Date</td>
      <td>Updated Date</td>
      <td>Time</td>
      <td>Status</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let report of reports">
          <td>{{ report.username }}</td>
          <td>{{ report.created_date }}</td>
          <td>{{ report.updated_date }}</td>
          <td>{{ report.time }}</td>
          <td>{{ report.status }}</td>

      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

but i got a error like this

**ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'Response with status: 200 OK for URL: http://localhost:3000/report' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

i don't know what is the problem

Comment: Check  this.userReport.getReport()… its not returning an array - is it returning a single report?. Try testing the URL in a browser. FYI, just because you cast the object to an array, does not make it so.

Comment: _NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays._

Comment: What do you receive in the data? Is it an array or object?

Comment: my data

Response {headers: Headers {_headers: Map(1), _normalizedNames: Map(1)} ok: true status: 200 statusText: "OK" type: 2 url: "localhost:3000/report" _body: "[{"_id":"5bec00c1043e8b3070858e36","username":"NAME","created_date":"Nov 14, 2018","updated_date":"Nov 14, 2018","time":"4:32 PM","status":"D","v":0},,]" __proto: Body}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix to convert your single report to an array:

```
getReport() {
        this.userReport.getReport()
            .subscribe((data: UserReport) => {
            this.reports = [data];
            console.log(data);
    });
    }
```

Comment: this.reports = [data._body]; it work correctly but in table noting is printed

Comment: why data._body? is _body a property you're returning in your json?

Comment: headers: Headers {_headers: Map(1), _normalizedNames: Map(1)}
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: 2
url: "http://localhost:3000/report"
_body: "[{"_id":"5bec00c1043e8b3070858e36","username":"NAME","created_date":"Nov 14, 2018","updated_date":"Nov 14, 2018","time":"4:32 PM","status":"D","__v":0},,]"
__proto__: Body

Comment: Looking at your json, _body is already an array.   Try `this.reports = data._body`;

Comment: i think loop is a problem if i print this {{reports}} it print but ngFor not working